# Is it possible to control these temperature?

Tags: arch-linux, hardware, power-management, temperature

As far as I know, it's not possible to enable fancontrol service or something like that for some HP Laptops, I'm using one such piece. While rendering a 6 min long clip in kdenlive, `sensors` readings were almost never under 80 degree:

[image]
in an ambient temperature of around 22 degree on a running 5 fan cooling deck.

### EDIT 1:

I've given it another try with another 18 min long video in kdenlive, it took about 11 min to produce and several times temperatures rose up to 100 degree.

[image]

I'm using [this](https://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-Pavilion-15-i7-6700HQ-GTX-950M-Notebook-Review.156312.0.html) one. It's an integrated Intel HD 530 and a dedicated NVIDIA.

Normally, when I read or write documents, execute C#/Qt code, it sticks around 35 degree and when I watch video, it's almost never less than 45 degree.

---

**EDIT 2:**

It doesn't do that much if I use GPU accelration in `shotcut` instead of CPUs in parallel in `kdenlive`, it took less than 2 and a half min to render the same 18 min video in `shotcut` and here's a snapshot of readings:

[image]

I don't know what `iTCO_wdt` and `iTCO_vendor_support` actually do BUT it looks like CPU temp reaches 100 degree less frequently if I keep those (nmi and soft) watchdogs enabled!

How long CPUs can run on an average temperature of 95 degree?

---

**EDIT 3:**
executed `sensors-detect`

```
[emon@haque ~]$ sudo sensors-detect 
# sensors-detect revision $Revision$
# System: HP HP Pavilion Gaming Notebook [Type1ProductConfigId] (laptop)
# Board: HP 80A9
# Kernel: 4.19.61-1-lts x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz (6/94/3)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no):     
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8987
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.4: Sunrise Point-H (PCH)
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 5040 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes
Client found at address 0x18
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95233'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95234'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95235'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM64'...                No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1047'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1402'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1403'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1404'...                               No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x19
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95231'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95241'...             No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM95245'...             No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No
Client found at address 0x1a
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1021A/ADM1023'...            No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1617A'...                             No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1668'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1805'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1989'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6655/MAX6656'...                      No
Probing for `TI THMC10'...                                  No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM84'...                No
Probing for `Genesys Logic GL523SM'...                      No
Probing for `Onsemi MC1066'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1618'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX1619'...                              No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM82/LM83'...           No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6654'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6690'...                              No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6680/MAX6681'...                      No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6695/MAX6696'...                      No
Probing for `Texas Instruments TMP400'...                   No
Probing for `Texas Instruments AMC6821'...                  No
Probing for `ST STTS424'...                                 No
Probing for `ST STTS424E'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS2002'...                                No
Probing for `ST STTS3000'...                                No
Probing for `NXP SE97/SE97B'...                             No
Probing for `NXP SE98'...                                   No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7408'...                     No
Probing for `IDT TS3000/TSE2002'...                         No
Probing for `IDT TSE2004'...                                No
Probing for `IDT TS3001'...                                 No
Probing for `Maxim MAX6604'...                              No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9804'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9808'...                          No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98242'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98243'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP98244'...                         No
Probing for `Microchip MCP9843'...                          No
Probing for `ON CAT6095/CAT34TS02'...                       No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS02C'...                              No
Probing for `ON CAT34TS04'...                               No
Probing for `Atmel AT30TS00'...                             No
Probing for `Giantec GT30TS00'...                           No


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

Do you want to generate /etc/conf.d/lm_sensors? (YES/no): 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/lm_sensors.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/lm_sensors.service.
Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

restarted after that and status is:

```
[emon@haque ~]$ sudo systemctl status lm_sensors.service 
[sudo] password for emon: 
● lm_sensors.service - Initialize hardware monitoring sensors
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lm_sensors.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-08-03 18:36:22 +06; 19min ago
  Process: 529 ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe -qab $BUS_MODULES $HWMON_MODULES (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 534 ExecStart=/usr/bin/sensors -s (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 534 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 03 18:36:21 haque systemd[1]: Starting Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...
Aug 03 18:36:22 haque systemd[1]: Started Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
```

checked with the same 18 min video in `kdenlive` again, here's 4 snapshots:

[image]

what to do next?

Comment: Please provide more information, such as model, distribution, integrated or discrete graphic...

Comment: Ok, since you have two graphic cards, I think it would be a good idea to start this *debug* by checking cards load (and thus temps). I have never used a video editor but I know they can encode/decode using graphic cards...

Comment: @mattia.b89, I've bbwitch on, NVIDIA loads only with optirun and offloads as soon as I quit programs like OBS. KDEnlive doesn't support hardware acceleration, it uses cpus.

Comment: Thus, it is normal to reach such high temps. In this case, the only way to **limit** CPU temp is to **cap** its power: you can do it via BIOS or softwares like *TLP* https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP

Comment: @mattia.b89, GPU didn't help CPUs, see `EDIT 2`!

Comment: I know you say it’s not possible to enable fan control on your laptop, but have you tried configuring `fancontrol`? If it knows about the controller in your system, it might be able to override the firmware and run the fans faster...

Comment: @StephenKitt, I wanted to BUT there's no `fancontrol` in `thermal zone directories` in `/sys`

Comment: Yes, you’d have to figure out the appropriate kernel modules to load. There’s a `sensors-detect` script in `lm-sensors` which will help you do that.

Comment: @StephenKitt, executed that and added the output in `EDIT 3` part.

Comment: OK, so `sensors-detect` didn’t find anything useful to control fans... Have you had a look in firmware setup? There might be fan control options there.

Comment: @StephenKitt, I don't know what's firmware! Where to look at?

Comment: When you power up the notebook, immediately press Esc then F10, before the operating system boots (I think that’s the right key sequence, check your manual if it doesn’t work).

Comment: @StephenKitt, oh! I didn't know that the BIOS and Firmware are same.

Comment: @StephenKitt, there;s an option `Fan Always On` and it's `Enabled`.

Comment: I may have missed the point here, but… are the fans actually running on full speed (just judge by ear)?

Comment: @Hermann, it does run at full speed and I can feel the heat by putting my hand near the ventilators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## There are options

Assuming the fans are running at full speed, manually *controlling* the speed won't do anything better. In general, you have three options:

1. Increase heat flow
2. Increase cooling area
3. Decrease heat generation

With a laptop, your options regarding 1 and 2 are very limited. You may want to check the air-flow. There might be dirt in the cooling fans. There also is the possibility that the thermally conductive glue is worn out. If this happens, the CPU heats up but the air blown out of the device is cool.

I recommend exploring option 3. Use [CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) or – in case they exist – the overclocking mechanisms of the BIOS to *underclock* the CPU. The rendering process will obviously take longer, but the system will stay cool.

For nVidia GPUs, you can also chose performance profiles and – sometimes — clock speeds.

Comment: It blows hot air through every ventilator, most of the heat comes out through the right hand side ventilator! I think Windows does that frequency scaling, on Windows 10 it definately would take more than 25 min to produce a 18 min long video on Premiere or Camtasia.

Comment: [Here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/537314/scaling-cpu-frequency) another question I've on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Temperature control is a wide issue that embraces many settings.

At glance, you talk about **fan control** in order to *fix* the temperature problem. Have you read this wiki[1] page?
Then, you can skim the **power management** wiki[2] which is the *origin* of your issue.

[1] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control
[2] https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management

Comment: Someone informed me that these laptops use ACPI to control the fans.