# Excessive temperature issue on Desktop

Tags: arch-linux, cpu, hardware, temperature

I thought that I wouldn't have the excessive temperature issue on the Desktop BUT it's actually worse than [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533669/is-it-possible-to-control-these-temperature) laptop!

[image]

What's that 255 degree under `PCI Adapter`? Is it real? `temp 2` under `ISA Adapter` went over 93 degree many times. Are any of those temperature of my cpu cores? I ran `sensors-detect` with all positive. Its fan always runs over `6000 rpm` and it was blowing excessive heat truely while rendering!

I stopped rendering on the desktop and moved the test project on that laptop. I don't know why this time that laptop performed better. Previously, within a minute temperatures rose up to 95 degree BUT this time it took about 7 mins to render that 16 min video; for first 5 mins all temperatures were below 85 degree, on 6th min it was in between 85 and 95 degree and on the last minute it exceeded 95 degree and reached 100 degree several times!

`tlp` by default doesn't make any difference!

---

**EDIT**

On the Desktop `lscpu` returns:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                      16
Model:                           4
Model name:                      AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor
Stepping:                        3
CPU MHz:                         800.000
CPU max MHz:                     3200.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        6400.04
Virtualization:                  AMD-V
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        6 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
Vulnerability L1tf:              Not affected
Vulnerability Mds:               Not affected
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Not affected
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full AMD retpoline, STIBP disabled, RSB filling
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht sy
                                 scall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid 
                                 extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dn
                                 owprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr hw_pstate vmmcall npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save
```

and `lspci` returns:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780L [Radeon 3000]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780 HDMI Audio [Radeon 3000/3100 / HD 3200/3300]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: I do not think that 175C is remotely possible for that pci adapter. 105C is the typical shutoff critical temperature for video adapters. CPUs experience massive slow downs when 90-100C is exceeded. Motherboard chips have a similar range of 105-115C. I would say that reaching that temperature could potentially be possible once, but I don't see how that device could remain functional afterwards. The core temperatures are reasonable for a close to a 100% load on all cores, although if this is a normal daily operation for this system, a cooling system upgrade is a must.

Comment: @BarBar1234, I ran it on 255 degree for 2 or 3 mins; it was stuck at 255 until I aborted the rendering.